# "java: no suitable method found for sort(java.util.ArrayList<Person>,<anonymous java.util.Comparator<Person>>)"

Tags: java

I don't understand why it doesn't work. I did an extensive research but didn't find a solution.
My goal is to sort the persons by lexicographical order and if they have the same name by age but I can't even make work this basic comparison.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("Guillaume", 20));
        persons.add(new Person("John", 50));
        persons.add(new Person("Guillaume", 10));
        persons.add(new Person("John", 10));
        persons.add(new Person("Luc", 5));
        System.out.println(persons.get(0).age);
        Arrays.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
                return (o1.age-o2.age);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(persons);
    }
}
     class Person {

        public String name;
        public int age;

        public Person(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + " " + age;
        }
        }
```

Comment: `Arrays.sort(...)` is used to sort an **array**. `persons` is a `List`, not an **array**. Call `Collections.sort(...)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the place of `Arrays.sort` use `Collections.sort`. The sort method which exists on Arrays is not used for sorting collections like arraylist, rather they are used for arrays having primitive data.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("Guillaume", 20));
        persons.add(new Person("John", 50));
        persons.add(new Person("Guillaume", 10));
        persons.add(new Person("John", 10));
        persons.add(new Person("Luc", 5));
        System.out.println(persons.get(0).age);
        Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
                return (o1.age-o2.age);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(persons);
    }
}
     class Person {

        public String name;
        public int age;

        public Person(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + " " + age;
        }
        }
```

**output**

20
[Luc 5, Guillaume 10, John 10, Guillaume 20, John 50]